# jQuery addClass/removeClass (Cannot read property 'length' of undefined)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I load my page I want some of my divs to be hidden from start and only show one, so this is the script that I found for that.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".total").click(function () {
            $("#piechart").removeClass('hidden');
            $("#piechartS").addClass('hidden');
            $("#piechartB").addClass('hidden');
            $("#piechartD").addClass('hidden');
        });
        $(".squat").click(function () {
            $("#piechart").addClass('hidden');
            $("#piechartS").removeClass('hidden');
            $("#piechartB").addClass('hidden');
            $("#piechartD").addClass('hidden');
        });
        $(".benchpress").click(function () {
            $("#piechart").addClass('hidden');
            $("#piechartS").addClass('hidden');
            $("#piechartB").removeClass('hidden');
            $("#piechartD").addClass('hidden');
        });
        $(".deadlift").click(function () {
            $("#piechart").addClass('hidden');
            $("#piechartS").addClass('hidden');
            $("#piechartB").addClass('hidden');
            $("#piechartD").removeClass('hidden');
        });
    });
</script>
```

and these are the divs

```
<div id="piechart" class="repPieChart"></div>                
<div id="piechartS" class="repPieChart hidden"></div>
<div id="piechartB" class="repPieChart hidden"></div>
<div id="piechartD" class="repPieChart hidden"></div>
```

CSS

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
.repPieChart {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #898989;
}
```

so the idea is that the first div doesnt have `hidden` class from the beginning so it's visible and the others hidden, and then when I click the a tag that is linked to this click events it will remove or add the hidden class to the correct divs, which it does, I checked the chrome code inspector thing and the class gets removed and added the correct way, however only the first div is visible, when I click to show another one I get the error in the title.

What could be wrong?

```
@{
Layout = "~/_SiteLayout.cshtml";
// Browser tab title.
Page.Title = "Repetitions";
// Opens connection to the database.
var db = Database.Open("SmallBakery");
// Gets the text typed into the textboxes and stores it in these variables.
var inputDate = Request.Form["inputDate"];
var endDate = Request.Form["endDate"];

var normOrAvg = Request.Form["NormOrAvg"];
// If no start date is selected, this will be used as the start date aka `inputDate`.
DateTime noStartDate = new DateTime(2000, 01, 01);
// If no end date is selected, this will be used as the end date.
DateTime noEndDate = DateTime.Now;

// If user does not choose eiter/any start/end date
// this will end up showing all results from `noStartDate` to todays date.
if (inputDate == "")
{
    inputDate = noStartDate.ToString("MMM d, yyyy");
}
if (endDate == "")
{
    endDate = noEndDate.ToString("MMM d, yyyy");
}
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {

            // Get Date from datepicker
            var date = $(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "M d, yy", showButtonPanel: true }).val

            // Use the date to create a Moment Object and format it so that it can be
            // used within the databse
            var databaseDate = moment(date).format('YY-MM-DD');

            // Use your correctly formatted date however you want, in this example
            // we are just console logging it to take a look if it's correctly parsed.
            console.log(databaseDate);

        });



    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.holdLiftMenu li a').on('click', function () {
                $('li a.current').removeClass('current');
                $(this).addClass('current');
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var elems = ['#piechart', '#piechartS', '#piechartB', '#piechartD']
            function show(item) {
                for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
                    if (elems[i] === item) {
                        $(elems[i]).show();
                    } else {
                        $(elems[i]).hide()
                    }
                }
            }
            $(".total").click(function () {

                show("#piechart");
            });
            $(".squat").click(function () {
                show("#piechartS");
            });
            $(".benchpress").click(function () {
                show("#piechartB");
            });
            $(".deadlift").click(function () {

                show('');
            });
        });
    </script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    @{ 
        // DateTime variable for the startdate textbox placeholder.
        DateTime placeholderStartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(noStartDate);

        <h1 class="metricsTitle"><a href="~/metrics/">Repetitions in Intensity</a></h1>
        <p class="blackColor">Analyze in what range of intensity you accumulate most of your repetitions.</p>

        // Form with date textboxes and submit button.
        <form method="post" action="~/AJAXcalls/repinintAJAX.cshtml" name="form">
            <div class="reportDateDiv">

                <a class="blackColor fSize18 RPtxt">Reporting Period</a>

                <input type="text" name="inputDate" spellcheck="false" class="datepicker metricDateTextbox capitalFirst"
                      onchange="mySubmit(this.form)" value="@inputDate" autocomplete="off" placeholder="@placeholderStartDate.ToString("MMM d, yyyy")" readonly="readonly" />

                <a class="blackColor fSize16 RPtxtTo">to</a>

                <input type="text" name="endDate" spellcheck="false" class="datepicker metricDateTextbox capitalFirst"
                      onchange="mySubmit(this.form)" value="@endDate" autocomplete="off" placeholder="@noEndDate.ToString("MMM d, yyyy")" readonly="readonly" />

                <select name="NormOrAvg" class="dwmViewSelect" onchange="mySubmit(this.form)">
                    <option selected=@(Request.Form["NormOrAvg"] == "1") value="1">Rep Per Set</option>
                    <option selected=@(Request.Form["NormOrAvg"] == "2") value="2">Average Rep Per Set</option>
                </select>
                </div>
        </form>

        <div class="holdLiftMenu">
            <ul class="holdLiftMenuUL">
                <li class="holdLiftMenuLI"><a class="holdLiftMenuA total current">Total</a></li>
                <li class="holdLiftMenuLI"><a class="holdLiftMenuA squat">Squat</a></li>
                <li class="holdLiftMenuLI"><a class="holdLiftMenuA benchpress">Benchpress</a></li>
                <li class="holdLiftMenuLI"><a class="holdLiftMenuA deadlift">Deadlift</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        // This div is updated with the data that is recieved from the background with the ajax information.
        <div id="here"></div>

        // Ajax script.
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function mySubmit(theForm) {
                $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
                    data: $(theForm).serialize(), // get the form data
                    type: $(theForm).attr('method'), // GET or POST
                    url: $(theForm).attr('action'), // the file to call
                    success: function (response) { // on success..
                        $('#here').html(response); // update the DIV
                    }

                });
            }
        </script>
    }
</body>
```

Comment: Can you please add the relevant css as well?

Comment: done @Hodrobond

Comment: Your code works fine. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EZqMvd

Comment: @PontusSvedberg we need the rest of your markup. Create a [mcve] that illustrates the problem.

Comment: where is the length error?

Answer (score 0):

i make an [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9wdagc1f/3/), expect it works:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var elems = ['#piechart', '#piechartS', '#piechartB', '#piechartD'];
show('');
    function show(item) {
        for(var i =0; i<elems.length;i++){
        if(elems[i]===item){
            $(elems[i]).show();
        }else{
        $(elems[i]).hide()
        }
      }
    }
            $(".total").click(function () {

                show("#piechart");
            });
            $(".squat").click(function () {
            show("#piechartS");
            });
            $(".benchpress").click(function () {
            show("#piechartB");
            });
            $(".deadlift").click(function () {

               show('');
            });
        });
```

**Edited, to works propertly and hide at start**

Comment: length? used where?, because my last edited gets no error

Comment: seen with my last updated, but in fiddle works wiothout any error

Comment: okey okey, ehh, when I remove the hidden class from all divs this works, when I add hidden to the last three so they are not visible from the beginning I get the error

Comment: just found that out now

Comment: great, expect helped you :)

Comment: is there a way to make them hidden from the beginning in this casE?

Comment: yes , easy https://jsfiddle.net/9wdagc1f/3/, call show(''); at the begining, or add display:none , to all

Comment: well, the `hidden` class is display: none, and that gave me the length errors :/

Comment: i think, your error is in you own server, in the fiddle posted not occurs

Comment: and adding show(") didnt work for me, I see it did in the fiddle but for me they all show up anyway, hehe

Comment: jajjja, strange anyway, needs to force reload your ap?

Comment: cleaned cache and all that and restarted page and reloaded and everything :/

Comment: btw, the divs doesnt exist in the beginning, they are on another page and called via ajax, so when the script is run on page load the divs doesnt exist yet, could that be the problem?

Comment: should I somehow run this script on the called ajax page as well?

Comment: If you are loading the divs via ajax, that could be part of your problem. You may want to put the hide() in the success callback of whatever method you use to load them.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working sample of what you posted -- what seems to be broken?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".total").click(function () {
            $("#piechart").removeClass('hidden');
            $("#piechartS").addClass('hidden');
            $("#piechartB").addClass('hidden');
            $("#piechartD").addClass('hidden');
        });
        $(".squat").click(function () {
            $("#piechart").addClass('hidden');
            $("#piechartS").removeClass('hidden');
            $("#piechartB").addClass('hidden');
            $("#piechartD").addClass('hidden');
        });
        $(".benchpress").click(function () {
            $("#piechart").addClass('hidden');
            $("#piechartS").addClass('hidden');
            $("#piechartB").removeClass('hidden');
            $("#piechartD").addClass('hidden');
        });
        $(".deadlift").click(function () {
            $("#piechart").addClass('hidden');
            $("#piechartS").addClass('hidden');
            $("#piechartB").addClass('hidden');
            $("#piechartD").removeClass('hidden');
        });
    });
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#piechart {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}
#piechartS {
  border: 1px dotted red;
}
#piechartB {
  border: 1px dotted green;
}
#piechartD {
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="piechart" class="repPieChart">A</div>                
<div id="piechartS" class="repPieChart hidden">S</div>
<div id="piechartB" class="repPieChart hidden">B</div>
<div id="piechartD" class="repPieChart hidden">D</div>

<button class="total">
Total!
</button>
<button class="squat">
Squat!
</button>
<button class="benchpress">
Benchpress!
</button>
<button class="deadlift">
Deadlift!
</button>
```

HOWEVER, you could shorten this considerably. below, I've added a data-for attribute to each button so that it refers to a specific div, then i simply show the relevant div and hide all its siblings:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".holdLiftMenuLI a").on("click", function() {
        $("#" + $(this).data("for")).removeClass("hidden")
          .siblings().addClass("hidden");
      });
    });
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.holdLiftMenuLI {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.holdLiftMenuLI a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#piechart {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
#piechartS {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
#piechartB {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
#piechartD {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="piechart" class="repPieChart">A</div>
  <div id="piechartS" class="repPieChart hidden">S</div>
  <div id="piechartB" class="repPieChart hidden">B</div>
  <div id="piechartD" class="repPieChart hidden">D</div>
</div>

<div class="holdLiftMenu">
  <ul class="holdLiftMenuUL">
    <li class="holdLiftMenuLI"><a class="holdLiftMenuA total current" data-for="piechart">Total</a></li>
    <li class="holdLiftMenuLI"><a class="holdLiftMenuA squat" data-for="piechartS">Squat</a></li>
    <li class="holdLiftMenuLI"><a class="holdLiftMenuA benchpress" data-for="piechartB">Benchpress</a></li>
    <li class="holdLiftMenuLI"><a class="holdLiftMenuA deadlift" data-for="piechartD">Deadlift</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And changing the above for li's and a's was simply a matter of changing the jquery selector -- everything else continues to work fine.

Comment: hmm, I like this, I dont use buttons tho, is it possible to recreate this with `<div class="holdLiftMenu">
                <ul class="holdLiftMenuUL">
                    <li class="holdLiftMenuLI"><a class="holdLiftMenuA total current">Total</a></li>
                    <li class="holdLiftMenuLI"><a class="holdLiftMenuA squat">Squat</a></li>
                    <li class="holdLiftMenuLI"><a class="holdLiftMenuA benchpress">Benchpress</a></li>
                    <li class="holdLiftMenuLI"><a class="holdLiftMenuA deadlift">Deadlift</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>`

Comment: oh, that looked like a mess haha

Comment: Done and done -- revisit that second example. It works via the li>a tags rather than the buttons. You'd still want to pretty the list with CSS, but functionality should remain unchanged.

Comment: for some reason it doenst change div, it remains on the first one, I see it works in the snippet though:/

Comment: and watching the chrome inspector the classes never change :/

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/ZeH6u a picture of it, squat is selected at the moment but the hidden class still remains